# Compilation error: BUG! exception after Griffon project upgrade

Tags: upgrade, griffon

I've working in a rich client with an Griffon 0.3.1 enviroment during the last couple of months.

That version is getting old and now I'm required to upgrade the project into a 0.9.3.

After doing:

```
griffon upgrade
```

And getting the latest releases of the required plugins I'm facing the following error:

```
Compilation error: BUG! exception in phase 'canonicalization' in source unit 'C:\maestro\desarrollo\projects\interactionManager\sgmentia-client\griffon-app\controllers\com\nortia\sgmentia\client\campaign\CampaignController.groovy' ClassNode#getTypeClass for com.nortia.sgmentia.business.Seleccion is called before the type class is set
```

There were no compilation errors before the upgrading after trying several things I haven't got a clue.

Thanks in advance.

Ivan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try upgrading to 0.9.4. There were some corner cases in previous versions due to the introduction of AST injection behavior. Also, don't forget to invoke the clean command right after upgrade.

Comment: I upgrade to 0.9.4 + clean but it doesnt work! :(. More ideas, please?

Comment: Could you please cross post to the Griffon User List? I believe the problem may be caused by a public method in the controller that looks like an action but it's not.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot. Trying to subscribe to follow the conversation. Meanwhile any suggestion to avoid the public method vs action issue?

Comment: You can either disable threading injection (see section 4.7.5 of the Griffon Guide) or make sure that all public methods in controllers follow the rules intended for actions (section 8.1).

Comment: Thank you again. It looks as if disabling the threading injection is working, but the migration itself is still a work in progress. By the way the [Mailing List] (http://xircles.codehaus.org/manage_email) is not working yet.

Comment: Right. Codehaus migrated some of its services to new servers last week. Some of the services may take more time to come back.

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I write my own conclusions in order to help anyone with the same problem.

- There is a big leap between Griffon 0.3.x and Griffon 0.9.x, some Apis have changed dramatically and AST Injection has been introduced.
- The following links **MUST** be read in order to understand what's going on:

http://griffon.codehaus.org/Griffon+0.9.2-rc1?print=1

http://dist.codehaus.org/griffon/guide/guide/9.%20Threading.html#9.3%20Annotation%20Based%20Threading

- If upgrading the straight way has not worked for you, try first disabling Threading injection:

`griffon.disable.threading.injection=true`

- Finally, once you get your code compiled you can try to clean your controllers step by step.

Hope it helps.