# Griffon Upgrade compilation error: mvcGroupInit repetitive method

Tags: groovy, upgrade, griffon

I'm upgrading a big 0.3.1 Griffon app into 0.9.4 I'm getting these difficulties:

1. Controlllers: 
   I've disabled UI Threading Injection in order to avoid the Compilation BUG issue (see [Compilation error: BUG! exception after Griffon project upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311492/compilation-error-bug-exception-after-griffon-project-upgrade))
   That's how I avoid that compilation error but then some other have appeared:

   ```
   [griffonc]
   [griffonc] C:\maestro\desarrollo\projects\interactionManager\sgmentia-client\griffon-app\controllers\com\nortia\sgmentia\client\select\SelectController.groovy: 53: Repetitive method name/signature for method 'void mvcGroupInit(java.util.Map)' in class 'com.nortia.sgmentia.client.select.SelectController'.

   [griffonc]  @ line 53, column 2.
   [griffonc]     void mvcGroupInit(Map args) {
   [griffonc]     ^
   [griffonc]

   [griffonc] C:\maestro\desarrollo\projects\interactionManager\sgmentia-client\griffon-app\controllers\com\nortia\sgmentia\client\select\SelectController.groovy: -1: Repetitive method name/signature for method 'void mvcGroupInit(java.util.Map)' in class 'com.nortia.sgmentia.client.select.SelectController'.
   [griffonc]  @ line -1, column -1.
   ```

It seems as if you were not allowed to overrride this method in a child controller. For example:

```
    class MyCommonController{
    ...
    }

    class MyChildController extends MyCommonController{
    ...
        void mvcGroupInit(java.util.Map){}
    }
```

I solved this error in other controllers doing the following refactoring:

```
    class MyCommonController{
    ...
        void mvcGroupInit(java.util.Map args){
        initMyCommon(map)
    }

    abstract void initMyCommon(map)
    }

    class MyChildController extends MyCommonController{
    ...
       void initMyCommon(map){
         //My real init code goes here
       }
    }
```

but this controller is more complicated to refactor:

```
    class SelectController extends WindowAdapter implements DocumentController
```

Is this the real problem? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.
Ivan.

Answer (score 0):

I've replicated the same settings but can get the application to work properly, at least if all controllers are found inside `griffon-app/controllers`. However if the base controller is placed in another directory, for example `src/main`, then you'll get this error.

This is a bug in Griffon that should be fixed. Would you care to post a JIRA ticket at http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/griffon?

Comment: Thank you :-) A fix has been posted already, it will be available in Griffon 0.9.5